# How to design different 'views' of a model RESTfully?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

By 'view' here I mean different combinations of properties of the model, not the view of the traditional MVC. For example, I have the following model:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :players
  belongs_to :status
  has_one :deck
  has_many :turns
  has_one :current_turn, :class_name => 'Turn', :conditions => ['turn_num = ?', '#{self.turn_num}']
end
```

I've written a `full_xml` method for Game that I use for the 'normal' get operation, so that I can include certain properties of players and current_turn, and then I don't have to do GETs on every player all the time. I also don't want to include ALL the properties and children and children's properties of the Game model on every GET

Now, however, I want to GET a game history, which is all the turns (and their properties/children). Initially I thought of a new model w/out a corresponding table, and then realized that wasn't necessary because the data and relationships are already there in the game and turns models. I also thought about writing a new action, but I thought I read somewhere that in the RESTful world, you shouldn't be writing any actions other than the core 7.

BTW, I'm thinking here of returning xml, because I'm using a Flex front end instead of rails views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options here - I would use "nested resources" so you end up with a  /game/:game_id/turns route which calls 'index' on the Turns controller. The other option is to create a GameHistory controller, which might be useful if there is additional logic associated with your game history.

There is not a one-to-one correspondence between controllers and models; there is however a one-to-one correspondence between controllers and RESOURCES. A game history is a whole different resource from a Game, just like a user session resource is different from an actual user resource (this is commonly used to allow for RESTful logins as well as RESTful user management) Hopefully this helps :)

Comment: Nested URIs have nothing to do with REST.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, nested resources was the answer. [This Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/139-nested-resources) explains it nicely. I had briefly tried nested resources before, and couldn't get it to work. It was returning **all** the child resources, not only the nested resource of the parent resource. This was because I assumed Rails was automagically doing that for me, which it doesn't. The Railscast explains that you still have to make changes to the controller of the child resources, like so:

```
class TurnsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /turns
  # GET /turns.xml
  def index
    @game = Game.find(params[:game_id])
    @turns = @game.turns

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @turns.to_xml( :except => [:created_at, :updated_at] ) }
    end
  end
  ... more methods
end
```

You also have to edit your routes.rb file. In this case, I want nested routes for both players and turns of the game, so I did this:

```
map.resources :games do |game|
    game.resources :players
    game.resources :turns
end
```